# Mutual Information for Jointly Distributed r.v.'s

Tags: probability, information-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly distributed discrete random variables. Show that $I(X; Y) ≥ I(f(X); g(Y))$, where $f(·)$ and $g(·)$ are given functions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: If it's true that $f(X)$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed as well (is this true??) then we have:

$I(f(X); g(Y)) <= I(f(X); Y) = I(Y; f(X)) <= I(Y; X) = I(X; Y)$

where both inequalities follow from the data processing inequality.